# MySQL query giving error 1064 - any ideas?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This query:

```
UPDATE jos_content SET fulltext='\r\n<br /> \" some other text' WHERE id=3
```

gives:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fulltext='\r\n<br /> \" some other text' WHERE id=3' at line 1`

Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Is it a typo here that you are missing a `;` at the end of the query?

Comment: trailing semicolons aren't required for single queries. Only if you were doing multiple queries would you need `;` to separate them, and MySQL doesn't allow multiple queries in a single query call.

Comment: @Raj, please do not edit the code. If there's an error in there that relates to the question, you've just obscured the error and confused everybody

Comment: @Johan Please check the edit history before you post comments. My edit was to format the code, not change it. You were the one to actually add a new line and edit the code.

Comment: @ray did look at the orig post, but must have misread sorry sorry 1000x sorry

Comment: @ray, rechecked the post history, you did change the code from **the original** by ed22 no idea why but that's how it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

fulltext is a reserved word.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

rename your field or put it within backticks '`' (alt + 96)

like so:

```
UPDATE jos_content SET `fulltext`='\r\n<br /> \" some other text' WHERE id=3
```

Comment: Alt+96 depends on the keyboard layout and operating system. My keyboard doesn't even have an Alt-key.